# How to enable Profiler on nginx?

Tags: magento-2.1, nginx, profiler

I can't enable Profiler on nginx. I have already added this line: `set $MAGE_PROFILER html` to file **devmagento2.conf**, but nothing was happened. I also have tried to add this line: `$_SERVER['MAGE_PROFILER'] = 'html`' to file **index.php**, with the same result.

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: i can only recommend the mirasvit/profiler module when you use nginx, worked for me. you can find the module on github

Answer (score 3):

For ngnix you have to write

```
fastcgi_param  MAGE_PROFILER html
```

into ngnix.conf file, you will find below code.

**File : ngnix.conf**

```
#PHP entry point for main application 
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n     suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=600";
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
# to configure profiler in Magento 2
fastcgi_param  MAGE_PROFILER $MAGE_PROFILER;

fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

set $MAGE_PROFILER html; this variable value can be set in virtual host config file or directly you can set *html* in place of variable $MAGE_PROFILER.
/etc/ngnix/conf.d/

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/local/local.key;
server_name example.com;    
set $MAGE_MODE developer;
set $MAGE_PROFILER html;
include /example.com/html/www/nginx.conf;
}
```

Comment: you saved my day :)